# pybind11 - convert arbitrary numpy arrays to vectors

Tags: c++, numpy, vector, pybind11

I'm trying to write a python plugin using pybind11 and hit an issue with getting the data conversion from numpy to std::vector types.
The python function is called with a dictionary of form:
`{"varname": numpy_array}`
All my trials end with a variation of casting error like `RuntimeError: Unable to cast Python instance of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> to C++ type 'std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >'`

the parsing function looks like this:

```
std::vector<float> Plg::process(py::dict &inputs)
{
  std::vector<std::string> keys;
  //len(data) == len(keys)
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> data; //!!! does not work
  for (auto item : inputs)
  {
    std::string k = py::cast<std::string>(item.first);
    keys.push_back(k);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> d = py::cast<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>(item.second);
    data.push_back(d);
  }
  //_process(data); - call to actual function, replace with dummy:
  std::vector<float> results;
  results.push_back(10.2);
  return results;
}
```

The `item` object is of type pybind11::handle and I can't seem to find definite list of members for it.
**under normal circumstances** I would just make my function take py::array_t, but sadly, the input must be a dictionary with string keys and semi arbitrary numpy arrays:

```
    std::vector<float> Plg::doit(py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> 
                                &input_vector)
    {
        std::vector<float> array_vector(input_vector.size());
        std::memcpy(array_vector.data(), input_vector.data()
                        , input_vector.size()*sizeof(float));
        std::vector<float> results = _process(array_vector);
        return results;
    }
```

The above however only works with data turned into an array beforehand in Python (flat numpy array). All threads that I found were dealing with an opposite problem - getting from vector to numpy which is not my case.

My question is twofold, first of all

1. How can I unpack an arbitrary numpy array and put it in flat std::vector?
2. Is there a smarter way that wouldn't require a memcpy?

I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm just not aware of, will greatly appreciate the help

---

### Update

My problem comes from different input sizes numpy tolerates - data coming in can be an array with dimensions (10, 10, 2) or just(200,) or even (2,) - it should all end up being a vector of float inside - something that seems to be handled well by py::array_t

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking was somewhat simple, but I'm not sure about the efficiency of it. The trick is to use the property of `py::array_t` and how it can handle an arbitrary numpy array. The issue is, the **buffer object has no valid end()** method (begin() returns correct value, end() returns null)

```
std::vector<float> Plg::proc(py::dict &inputs)
{
    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    for(auto item : inputs)
    {
            std::string k = py::cast<std::string>(item.first);
            keys.push_back(k);  // string part is trivial
    // create a storage element using pyarray cast defining it from second element of the map:
            auto buffer = py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>::ensure(item.second);
            if(!buffer)
            {
                std::cout << "no buffer loaded!" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
    // put raw data into a float vector. This relies on numpy arrays being contigeuous and contineous in memory. The previous problem came from buffer.end() being null so constructing from begin() and end() is doomed to fail!. Calculate item size using bytes in the buffer and item size.
                std::vector<float> d(buffer.data(), buffer.data()+buffer.nbytes()/buffer.itemsize());
                data.push_back(d);
            }
        
    }
    do_stuff(data, keys);
}
```

Would be nice if pybind came with more in depth examples, but overall, it's a great library.